# .split() method in Java not found

Tags: java, split

I am doing a `TextReader()` class in Java for an assignment, and I am trying to separate a `String` by any whitespaces, like so:

```
 String[] splitString;

 while (readLine != null) {
   //assign each word to an array

   splitString = splitString.split("\\s+");

}
```

however, I get the error "cannot find symbol split()" i've looked at some previous questions and nothing has worked.

Comment: What is `splitString`? What is it declared as? Does that type have a `split` method?

Comment: i declared it as a String at the top of my code, i'll edit the question

Comment: It's  not a `String`, it's a `String[]`. There's a big difference which you should look into. Array types only have the methods declared in `Object`.

Comment: i just edited the question - i put `String[]`

Comment: For an example how to split a `String` in Java you could look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) on StackOverflow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `splitString` should be a String object to use split.
Be sure that you have that declaration of it

```
String splittString = readLine.toString();
String[] splittedStringsArray = splittString.split('\\s+');
```

[String split reference.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: sorry, i meant to say, i declared that at the beginning of my code. i have `String splitString;` at the top :)

Comment: Remeber that String.split() method returns an array of Strings.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `splitString` variable should be a `String` which you could split, but you have declared it as a `String[]`. Assuming you are using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) object `scanner` (wild guess since you're reading using a while loop), what you probably want to do is:

```
ArrayList<String> splitString = new ArrayList<String>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    for (String s : scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+")) {
        splitString.add(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`split()` is a method that belongs to the `String` class. Your `splitString` is an array o Strings, therefore it cannot as a whole use the split() method.
For that to work you would have to use something like `splitString = splitString[0].split("\\s")`

Answer (score 1):

This is the same happen to me just now. I start a new Kafka stream app with the maven. The command is here,

```
$ mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.kafka \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=streams-quickstart-java \
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.0.0 \
    -DgroupId=streams.examples \
    -DartifactId=streams.examples \
    -Dversion=0.1 \
    -Dpackage=myapps
```

I get a code snippet like this auto-generated,

```
builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input")
                .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split("\\W+")))
                .to("streams-linesplit-output");
```

This shows an error `Cannot Resolve Method split(java.lang.String)`. Obviously, the `split` method belongs to the `String` class and hence, I had it to chnage as following,

```
builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input")
                .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toString().split("\\W+")))
                .to("streams-linesplit-output");
```

I'm curious why the maven archetypes provide a wrong code snippet. I'm talking about the Java 8